# Why the bootstrap button which is working on browsers on PC and laptop is not working on devices like smartphones and tablets?

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, iphone, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm using **bootstrap framework v2.0.1** for my website.

There is one button on my page which is working fine on browsers when the site is viewed on a PC or laptop. The issue is on devices like smart phones and tablets.

I tried to detect the issue with the help of firebug console but there is no such error or warning come. That means the jQuery code is working absolutely fine.

So I'm not getting what is the issue in the button to work on devices. Can someone please help me in this regard?

The code is as follows:

```
<div class="container" style="padding-top: 140px; margin-bottom: 70px;">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span12 account-container12">        
      <legend>My Profile <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="location.href = 'http://sample.site.com/change_password.php';" style="float:right">Change Password</button></legend> 
    </div>
  </div>
</div> <!-- /container -->
```

Comment: what exactly istn working? did you try something like `onclick="alert('ok');"` dose this fire?

Comment: @reyaner:yes I tried that as well. The alert came when I test on PC/laptop but on devices I was not able to click the button. Even I tried to replace the button with anchor tag but that also didn't work on devices.

Comment: ok, then i assume that something is laying over the area you trying to click... if you have a mac, you could inspect with console on iphone oder ipad, if there is something over it.. or maybe position:absolute; with z-index, also to test if you could click it then...

Comment: @reyaner:Yes, I tried to view again in firebug console on iPhone simulator. Then I got following code in firebug :
<button style="float:right" onclick=" _proxy_jslib_assign('',  _proxy_jslib_handle(null, 'location', location, 0, 0), 'href', '=', ( 'http://sample.site.com/change_password.php'));" class="btn btn-primary" type="button">Change Password</button>

Comment: I dont think, that an Iphone sim. shows you the real thing, that you might get on the Iphone it self... so you would have to inspect on the iphone it self, not on an simulator... a quick check would be, like i said, setting it absoulute or placeing the button somewhere else, just to be sure its not an issue with overlaying div or something...

Comment: You should upgrade to at least Bootstrap v2.3.2 (or if this is a new site, use Bootstrap v3), there have been many bug fixes.